# Unable to install yum on cpanel server

Tags: linux, centos, yum, cpanel

I recently signed up on godaddy and have a user account on cpanel

I can successfully use ssh to login to my server

this is my operating system details when i use `uname -a`

```
Linux a2plcpnl0360.prod.iad2.secureserver.net 2.6.32-531.29.2.lve1.3.11.10.el6.x
86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 12 15:09:02 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am not a centos specialist (more of a debian user)

I am trying to install some python packages (such as mysql) using `yum`

this is my command line

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

this is the error

```
-bash:yum command not found
```

I tried using `which yum` but it returns nothing

Also I attempted to download the yum package manually and installed with `rpm` but rpm isn't installed...

Some help will be appreciated..

Comment: This was answered in a different forum: [Installing software on a shared linux godaddy server](http://serverfault.com/questions/315110/installing-software-on-a-shared-linux-godaddy-server).

Answer (score 2):

That is completely accurate. You are unable to install anything via SSH, or anything outside Installitron on CPanel w/ GoDaddy due to the Shared hosting. They state that it takes too many resources and you need a VPS or Dedicated server to do anything at that level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pulling in the [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/315118/293440) answer given by [nce](https://serverfault.com/users/95757/nce), just to give this Q a proper answer.

---

It seems that you are not allowed to gain root (superuser/su) privilege. Otherwise you may have received another different password from godaddy, for (your) root account.

It is not uncommon for shared hosting solutions to permit you ssh/shell access, but deny you root privilege.

You could either directly download the software you want to install, and go on with the linux building process (`configure && make && make install`). But I assume, without root, you will fail there too (depends on the software you want to install). And please read your TOS and stick to them. Installing software might be prohibited.

The best option would be to contact the support. Ask them, if they could install the software you need.

An upgrade of your hosting plan, to a dedicated/vps solution (with real root access) might be the last option.